# Continuation of a Loop Using Switch Statement Variable

Tags: java, date, loops, printing, switch-statement

I am attempting to have this program read out the dates 1/1 through 12/31 consecutively each on an individual line.  So far I have succeeded in printing 1/1 through 1/31, but I am lost as to how to continue my loop so that it will include the rest of the months/days.  I know there is an easier way to do this using the calendar, but I am avoiding that route.

```
public class LoopDate {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int startingDayOfWeek = 2;

    boolean isLeapYear = false;

    int month = 1;
    int year = 2000;
    int numDays = 0;
    switch (month) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 10:
    case 12:
        numDays = 31;
        break;
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
        numDays = 30;
        break;
    case 2:
        if (((year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 100 == 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))
            numDays = 29;
        else
            numDays = 28;
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid month.");
        break;
    }
    int start = 1;

    do {
        System.out.println(month + "/" + start);
        start++;
    } while (start <= numDays);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the switch statement and put it in the loop - or even better put it in a separate method which you call from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Add an enclosing loop.

```
public class LoopDate {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int startingDayOfWeek = 2;

    boolean isLeapYear = false;
    int year = 2000;
    int numDays = 0;
    for(int month = 1; month <= 12;month++){
        switch (month) {
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 10:
        case 12:
            numDays = 31;
            break;
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            numDays = 30;
            break;
        case 2:
            if (((year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 100 == 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))
                numDays = 29;
            else numDays = 28;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid month.");
            break;
        }
        for(int start=1;start<=numDays;start++) System.out.println(month + "/" + start);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked exactly as I had planned.  Would you also know how to seclude certain dates from these print outs.  Such as, if I wanted to exclude certain days of the year? AKA: 1/1 1/2 1/4 1/5..etc

Comment: Add a `if(month==someNumber && start==someDay) continue;` to the last for loop (You will need to open and close braces so you don't lose the println call). If you're looking to exclude multiple days, use an array with this.

Comment: I am trying to exclude all "Friday the 13th" dates from the list no matter what year is entered into the year variable.  That is why I have the "startingDayOfWeek" variable to track the fridays based on the first day of the year that is hard-coded in.  I am trying to track the friday and the start so if they end up on a friday and a 13 it will skip the print.  Would that be possible?